# Flask Sample webpage that request input from user performs no action

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I trying to learn how to code in Flask and am building a small portal that accepts inputs from the user (User could select among various check boxes). Based on the input I am trying to display the selected columns by means of an excel file. Given below what I have done thus far and I am not sure how to take this forward.

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET','POST'])
def user_input():
    form = SampleForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        Username = form.username_field.data
        Age = form.age_field.data
        output = user_input(Username,Age)
    return render_template('index', form=form)
```

I have managed to build the above code by reading through various blogs and posts but this does nothing. Could anyone guide me on where am I going wrong with the above sample piece of code. Thanks

Class.py

```
class test(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

Python function:

```
def function(*field_names):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    dwh_cursor.execute('select {} from enrolments'.format(', '.join(str(field) for field in field_names)))
    print(field_names)
    output_file = dwh_cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: What needs to happen after validate_on_submit? For instance a redirect to a new route where the form input is used to do whatever you want it to do?

Comment: @gittert, I am trying to pass these as input to a SQL query and from there return back an output from a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? Might need some tweaking to fit your needs.

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET','POST'])
def user_input():
    form = SampleForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        newform = User(
            username = form.username_field.data,
            age = form.age_field.data,
            )
        db.session.add(newform)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('user_input'))

    return render_template('user_input', form = form)
```

Comment: if I don't have a login in place can I remove current_user.. I am just trying to have a generic webpage where users can select relevant fields.. This is more of an internal website so won't be having a login page as such..

Comment: thanks for the edit, I am getting a Syntax error on the line "username = form.username_field.data".. Could you please assist.. Thanks..

Comment: please post your model class to your original question above. The names need to be the same as the attributes in the User class. Please also post the exact error trail in debug mode. I also just made a new edit, forgot an important thing :)

Comment: thanks. just change my code to the correct class name (I used User as class name), that should work just fine.

Comment: thanks for the edit.. Getting an error saying "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function". Is there something you could assist. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the initial post with the function to which I am trying to pass the output we just build.. Could you please assist how could I tweak this such that I am able to pass the values entered by the user to this SQL query. Thanks.

Comment: when I try to execute the code I get an error "NameError: name 'User' is not defined
"

Comment: Please then read my comment carefully where i stated to change the class name User to test. Or change test to User in your model. Also I would advise to do a.bit of studying on flask, we all have to start somewhere. i can say the flask mega tutorial of miguel helped me a lot in understanding flask, databases and syntax, and I'm still learning new stuff everyday..

Comment: thanks for all the help.. I am reading on flask as well and would have a look at the one you referred..